# Correct approach to delete the user interface data after database on cascade delete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, software-design

I have the relation 1 Company has many Organisations

My treeview with Organisations is shown on the left side in the user interface.

A "delete company"-button opens a modal delete dialog.

In the dialog I selected a company to delete and confirm.

Now the company is deleted in the database with an ajax post.

if the **result.success** is **true** then I have **2** choices.

My question is now wich one is better and why?

1. Delete the whole organisation tree by doing $('#TreeView').empty(); which clears everything inside the div
2. "Delete" the whole organisation tree by doing a $('#TreeView').load(UrlToGetTreeHierarchy) which should return an empty tree collection.

Both has same effect but point 2 accesses the database again.

What is best practice in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely number 1.  There's no benefit in asking for an empty dataset.  That would require a request, a database query and then a response.  The first method simply clears the data that has already been confirmed to be deleted.